# Casting GeckoNode to GeckoElement or SvgElement in SVG document fails. Geckofx 22.0.6

Tags: c#, dom, svg, gecko, geckofx

I am embedding geckofx v22.0.6 into a .Net 4 C# Winforms test app. Using geckofx LoadHtml() to put SVG content into gecko's document. SVG snippet (formatted for readability):

```
<!-- 8 -->
<g id='node3' class='node'>
    <title>8</title>

    <polygon fill='red'
             stroke='red'
             points='571,-828 517,-828 517,-792 571,-792 571,-828'/>

    <text text-anchor='middle' x='544' y='-806.3'
          font-family='Times New Roman,serif' font-size='14.00'
          fill='white'>

        8(1)

    </text>
</g>
```

Handling DomMouseOver event on my form:

```
void m_gb_DomMouseOver(object sender, Gecko.DomMouseEventArgs e)
{
    var tgt = e.Target.CastToGeckoElement();

    if (tgt.NodeName.ToLower() == "text")
    {
        var parent = tgt.ParentNode;

        foreach (var child in parent.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (child.NodeName.ToLower() != "polygon")
                continue;

            var poly = child as GeckoElement;
        }
    }
}
```

poly variable is always null. In debugger's watch window I tried casting child to all sorts of things (SvgElement, GeckoElement, etc), it just wants to stay GeckoNode. Why is this?

Comment: Instead of trying to cast it, why don't you print it's runtime type (`child.GetType()`) and start investigating from there?

Comment: @user2266486 type is Element, as expected. Done that. Also it shows tag name correctly as "polygon". It is strange that child.ParentElement is Gecko.DOM.Svg.SvgElement, however all children of parent (including child) are just GeckoNode's

Comment: One more thing that I almost forgot: tested on a regular html fragment (i.e., *not* svg) and it works .. puzzled

Comment: It's a bug in geckofx: https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-22.0/issue/54/casting-geckonode-to-geckoelement-for-svg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in the GeckoFx's QueryInterface. https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-22.0/issue/54/casting-geckonode-to-geckoelement-for-svg

Fixed in the tip of v22.0.6